# Paste column of text when there are more cursors than the selected column

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have something like this:

```
a1 = "1"
b1 = "1"
c1 = "blue"
d1 = "1"

a2 = "2"
b2 = "2"
c2 = "blue"
d2 = "2"

a3 = "3"
b3 = "3"
c3 = "red"
d3 = "3"

//values
5
5
blue
6
```

I want the values column on each group that the C variable has the "blue" value. The end result should be like that:

```
a1 = "5"
b1 = "5"
c1 = "blue"
d1 = "6"

a2 = "5"
b2 = "5"
c2 = "blue"
d2 = "6"

a3 = "3"
b3 = "3"
c3 = "red"
d3 = "3"
```

The way i was trying to do was selecting the blue value, ctrl+D to find blue values on other groups and then using ctrl+alt+down and up to select the values on other rows, the problem is that vscode wont let me paste the same column on all selected groups, instead it pastes the values columns on all rows (a1 = 5 5 blue 5, b1 = 5 5 blue 5, etc), i think it`s because it doesn`t have a 1:1 map. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

- start cursor before your first `5` value
- use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>DownArrow</kbd> to mark all the value lines
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>  // copy your values
- select your `= "blue"`
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> select all similar texts
- <kbd>LeftArrow</kbd> to get before all `=`
- <kbd>RightArrow</kbd> twice to get after `=`, before `"`
- <kbd>UpArrow</kbd> as many times as to reach first line in block
- use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>DownArrow</kbd> to mark all the lines in the block
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>
- <kbd>"</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
- <kbd>Esc</kbd>

Comment: it works for a single column but not when using the ctrl+shift+l to change all groups at the same time

Comment: @adrianonetto: it was written by hard and when I tried It does not what it supposed to do. We now have N*4 target cursors and 4 source strings.

Answer (score 0):

1. Turn on "**Column Selection Mode**"  `Selection/Column Selection Mode`
2. Select and copy your values to paste.
3. Select the column you want to replace (see demo)
4. Paste and add the `"`.

[image: column selection mode]

---

Do you want to automate many of these in a file?  Or is one-by-one okay?

You might have to use a find/replace if you want to do a bunch at once. See https://regex101.com/r/XFOVxA/1

`(.+ = ")(.+)("\n.+ = ")(.+)("\s.*blue"\n.+ = ")(.+")`

and replace with

`$15$35$56"`

Demo:

[image: regex demo]

Comment: I'd like to change everything or at least automate this because i have to do this 100+ times this way